# Why does the MethodMatcher interface in Spring Framework takes a targetClass as argument, where Pointcut already defines a Classfilter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

The [Pointcut](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/Pointcut.html) interface in [Spring Framework](https://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/) consists of 2 methods:

```
public interface Pointcut {

    /**
     * Return the ClassFilter for this pointcut.
     * @return the ClassFilter (never {@code null})
     */
    ClassFilter getClassFilter();

    /**
     * Return the MethodMatcher for this pointcut.
     * @return the MethodMatcher (never {@code null})
     */
    MethodMatcher getMethodMatcher();


    /**
     * Canonical Pointcut instance that always matches.
     */
    Pointcut TRUE = TruePointcut.INSTANCE;

}
```

The [ClassFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/ClassFilter.html) interface is already stating that, it is sole purpose is to decide whether a class can pass the filter or not:

```
/**
 * Filter that restricts matching of a pointcut or introduction to
 * a given set of target classes.
 *
 * <p>Can be used as part of a {@link Pointcut} or for the entire
 * targeting of an {@link IntroductionAdvisor}.
 *
 * @author Rod Johnson
 * @see Pointcut
 * @see MethodMatcher
 */
public interface ClassFilter {

    /**
     * Should the pointcut apply to the given interface or target class?
     * @param clazz the candidate target class
     * @return whether the advice should apply to the given target class
     */
    boolean matches(Class<?> clazz);


    /**
     * Canonical instance of a ClassFilter that matches all classes.
     */
    ClassFilter TRUE = TrueClassFilter.INSTANCE;

}
```

What I do not understand is, **why does the methods in the** [MethodMatcher](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/MethodMatcher.html) **interface again checks for class eligibility? Why the methods of this interface have the targetClass arguments?**

```
public interface MethodMatcher {

    /**
     * Perform static checking whether the given method matches. If this
     * returns {@code false} or if the {@link #isRuntime()} method
     * returns {@code false}, no runtime check (i.e. no.
     * {@link #matches(java.lang.reflect.Method, Class, Object[])} call) will be made.
     * @param method the candidate method
     * @param targetClass the target class (may be {@code null}, in which case
     * the candidate class must be taken to be the method's declaring class)
     * @return whether or not this method matches statically
     */
    boolean matches(Method method, Class<?> targetClass);

    /**
     * Check whether there a runtime (dynamic) match for this method,
     * which must have matched statically.
     * <p>This method is invoked only if the 2-arg matches method returns
     * {@code true} for the given method and target class, and if the
     * {@link #isRuntime()} method returns {@code true}. Invoked
     * immediately before potential running of the advice, after any
     * advice earlier in the advice chain has run.
     * @param method the candidate method
     * @param targetClass the target class (may be {@code null}, in which case
     * the candidate class must be taken to be the method's declaring class)
     * @param args arguments to the method
     * @return whether there's a runtime match
     * @see MethodMatcher#matches(Method, Class)
     */
    boolean matches(Method method, Class<?> targetClass, Object... args);


    /**
     * Canonical instance that matches all methods.
     */
    MethodMatcher TRUE = TrueMethodMatcher.INSTANCE;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `targetClass` specified in `MethodMatcher.matches(Method method, Class<?> targetClass)`**is not used for checking the eligibility of a target invocation class**.

It is used for **finding the most specific target method** which is applicable to the target class for a given method (specified as a parameter). It also resolves issues with [Java bridge methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html).

Here is a sample `matches` method from `org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut` class.

```
public boolean matches(Method method, Class<?> targetClass, boolean beanHasIntroductions) {
    this.checkReadyToMatch();
    Method targetMethod = AopUtils.getMostSpecificMethod(method, targetClass);
    ShadowMatch shadowMatch = this.getShadowMatch(targetMethod, method);
    ...
}
```

Here is the Javadoc from [org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils#getMostSpecificMethod](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/support/AopUtils.html#getMostSpecificMethod-java.lang.reflect.Method-java.lang.Class-)

> Given a method, which may come from an interface, and a target class used
>   in the current AOP invocation, find the corresponding target method if there is one. E.g. the method may be `IFoo.bar()` and the target class may be `DefaultFoo`. In this case, the method may be `DefaultFoo.bar()`. This enables attributes on that method to be found.
>
> **NOTE:** In contrast to `org.springframework.util.ClassUtils#getMostSpecificMethod`, this method resolves Java 5 bridge methods in order to retrieve attributes from the *original* method definition.